# RestKit 0.2* - Mapping multi-level relationship with RKRelationshipMapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

So there is a JSON File like this:

```
{
  "eventList" : [
    {
      "eventID" : 1,
      "comment" : "Connected at place.",
      "eventTypes" : [
        {
          "eventContextTypes" : [
            {
              "eventContextTypeID" : 14,
              "eventContextTypeText" : "Hospital",
            }
          ],
          "eventTypeID" : 2,
          "eventTypeText" : "Connection"
        }
      ],
      "submittedDate" : "2014-07-16T20:24:04Z"
    },
    {
      "eventID" : 2,
      "comment" : "Connected at place.",
      "eventTypes" : [
        {
          "eventContextTypes" : [
            {
              "eventContextTypeID" : 11,
              "eventContextTypeText" : "Location"
            }
          ],
          "eventTypeID" : 2,
          "eventTypeText" : "Connection"
        }
      ],
      "submittedDate" : "2014-06-16T20:10:51Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my app, I do have multiple calls where there is the `EventType` call with the mapping like this:

```
[eventTypeMapping addPropertyMappingsFromArray:@[[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:EventTypeRelationships.eventContextTypes
                                                                                             toKeyPath:EventTypeRelationships.eventContextTypes
                                                                                           withMapping:eventContextTypeMapping]]];
```

And then the `eventList` call, and the mapping is like this:

```
[newsFeedMapping addPropertyMappingsFromArray:@[[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"eventList"
                                                                                            toKeyPath:@"eventList"
                                                                                          withMapping:eventTypeMapping]]];
```

The problem is with mapping the value of the `eventContextTypes`. For some reason, it only saves the mapping data of the last object that is mapped. For example, when I call the JSON file, it maps `Hospital` and then overrides it with `Location` (the second value in the array) for the first object. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

EventTypeMapping and EventContextMapping are defined like such:

```
RKObjectMapping *eventTypeMapping = [EventType mapping];
RKObjectMapping *eventContextTypeMapping = [EventContextType mapping];
```

**====== UPDATE ======**

Here is the Mapping function for both `EventTypes` and `EventContextType`

```
// EVENTTYPE

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    // Create a singleton instance of the mapping object.
    __strong static RKEntityMapping *_mapping = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore];
        _mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) inManagedObjectStore:store];

        // Map attributes with the same name in the JSON and the model.
        // Use the string constants provided by mogenerator.
        [_mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"eventTypeID" : EventTypeAttributes.eventTypeID,
                                                       @"eventTypeText" : EventTypeAttributes.eventTypeText}];

        // Set primaryKeyAttribute
        _mapping.identificationAttributes = @[EventTypeAttributes.eventTypeID];

        // Relationships are mapped elsewhere
    });
    return _mapping;
}
```

And the `EventContextType` mapping:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {
    // Create a singleton instance of the mapping object.
    __strong static RKEntityMapping *_mapping = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        RKManagedObjectStore *store = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] managedObjectStore];
        _mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) inManagedObjectStore:store];

        // Map attributes with the same name in the JSON and the model.
        // Use the string constants provided by mogenerator.
        [_mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"eventContextTypeID" : EventContextTypeAttributes.eventContextTypeID,
                                                       @"eventContextTypeText" : EventContextTypeAttributes.eventContextTypeText}];

        // Set primaryKeyAttribute
        _mapping.identificationAttributes = @[EventContextTypeAttributes.eventContextTypeID];

        // Relationships are mapped elsewhere
    });
    return _mapping;
}
```

Here is the Model design:

[image]

**======= UPDATE ENDS =======**

Comment: Do you have any identification attributes? You should show the full mappings and the model class definitions...

Comment: @Wain yes, i do have the identification attributes set. The mapping works when I leave it to two levels deep in the JSON, or if I call those individual objects directly. It just seem to overwrite all the values when it is three levels deep. By the way, I've updated the Question.

Comment: After you have run the request and the response is processed, fetch everything from the data store and look for duplicate objects, some with relationships and some without - are there any. You have a lot of circular relationships so how are they all being populated? When you say `it maps Hospital and then overrides it with Location` how are you verifying that (by relationship contents). This could be a NewsFeed identification or relationship population issue, but I'm not sure yet...

Comment: @Wain, I ran the request, processed it and fetched from the store and printed out the values with all the relationships and data. They have the correct relationships (depending on the JSON) but no duplicates, the Identification attributes seem to be working. When I said `it maps Hospital and then overrides it with Location`, I mean that the first object maps properly with `Event -> EventType -> EventContextType` and the right values in them. But when mapping the second object, the `EventContextType` of the first object changed to `Location` which is supposed to be for the second one.

Comment: So, I modified the JSON to have `EventTypes` and `EventContextTypes` as two different object and not nested in the original structure. This structure worked for me. But if you (or anyone reading this) could shed light on why my original problem was happening, that would be great.